# Can’t commit and push in Git because “cannot spawn gpg2: No such file or directory”

Tags: git, git-commit, gnupg

Anytime I've tried to commit a change through the command line I've received this error message:

```
error: cannot spawn gpg2: No such file or directory
```

Update:
I'm running Windows 10

Comment: Have you solved it? Im experiencing same issue on Win 11

Answer (score 21):

(using Github Desktop in Windows 10)

after making new gpg like in below link, (I wanted to sign my commits)

https://gist.github.com/BoGnY/f9b1be6393234537c3e247f33e74094a

in command, I could use `git commit` without any errors.

but in the desktop application, I got the same error, and setting gpg path worked for me. (with verified commit with app)

```
where gpg
```

it will give something like "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe"

and using git bash, try this command

```
git config --global gpg.program "/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/gpg.exe"
```

Comment: And in case you forget the "" around the path and accidentally add multiple valuesto the config, use "git config --global --unset-all gpg.program to get a clean slate

Comment: Effective solution on windows 10 - the problem occur with me on Github desktop app, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the program used to sign commits is `gpg`.  On your system, it's been configured to `gpg2`.

Normally, signed commits are only generated when you either specify them with `-S` or when you have `commit.gpgsign` set to `true`, in which case all commits are signed.  If you want to continue to sign commits, you can change the binary used to sign them by running `git config --global gpg.program gpg`, assuming that `gpg` exists on your system.  (You can check by running `command -v gpg` and seeing if it provides any output.)

If `gpg` doesn't exist on your system, you can install it from your system package manager.  Often the name of the package is `gnupg`, but it may differ.  You haven't said what operating system you're using, so we can't provide you more specific information.

If you don't want to sign commits, then you can run `git config --unset-all commit.gpgsign` and signing will default to being disabled.

Answer (score -5):

You can disable GPG commit signing in Git by setting `commit.gpgsign` to false:

```
git config --global commit.gpgsign false
```

Comment: We could disable GPG signing, yes. But this is not a good solution for this question.

Comment: @Ishan OP never said they *wanted* GPG signing. It's **a** solution, even if it's not the one you want.